# Android Google Text-To-Speech Language Support

Tags: android, localization, text-to-speech, google-developers-console, google-text-to-speech

Hi i am developing a TTS voice based application which supports languages which is been supported by Google Text To Speech,

Currently i am getting the all the list of available languages by the following code,

```
      Set<Locale> locales = t1.getAvailableLanguages();
```

which is listing out some 54 set of locale including tamil. But when i try to speak the text with the application by following code,

```
         t1 = new TextToSpeech(getApplicationContext(), new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInit(int status) {
            if (status != TextToSpeech.ERROR) {
                // Lets say string i want to read is
                String toSpeak = "வணக்கம்";

                    try {
               //lets say i want to speak the Tamil Language here from the list given by t1.getAvailableLnaguages();
                        String localCode = "ta";
                        Locale locale = new Locale(localCode);
                        t1.setLanguage(locale);
                        t1.speak(toSpeak, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null, "1");
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                } 
            });
```

This code speaks the text in English Accent which is not understandable. Can anyone help me how to check if particular voice data has been installed in the device? Or correct me if i am doing something wrong with the perspective.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you want to speech convert English or other language

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Nope I do not want to convert some speech. But i want to speech the converted text(I have already done conversion to Tamil Language) by TTS(Text-To-Speech Engine).

Comment: @Shariku, did you found any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Locale code for tamil is

```
String localCode = "ta-IN";
```

Comment: What for Arabic, Persian, Hebrew? I will use this codes  "Arabic": "ar-YE", "Hebrew":"iw-IL", "Persian":"fa-IR"